# Invoking script from Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am brand new to selenium and am having trouble figuring out how to use Python and Selenium web driver to automate the following statement. This is a clickable text element "My Button Label".

```
<a class="class_a" href="javascript:f_func(46)" id="func46" ondrag="window.event.returnValue=false" onmousedown="return false;">My Button Label </a>
```

I've tried this:

```
driver.execute_script("f_func()", 46)
```

and this

```
driver.execute_script("f_func(46)")
```

but end up with

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'data[i] is undefined' ;
```

which points to a `var` deep inside js.

What is proper way to simulate clicking on that element and invoking the script, passing in 46 as argument?

On edit:  I forgot to add the first thing I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xx().click()
```

Also failed.  The ActionChain Api per below is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: why the down vote? this is a reasonable question for someone identified as a beginner/non-expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke script, have you tried sending your argument?

```
driver.execute_script("f_func(arguments[0])", 46)
```

But what's wrong with clicking in the first place? If it doesn't work for you, please try use `ActionChains`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# your code here

# then
ActionChains(driver).click(driver.find_element_by_id('func46')).perform()
```

Comment: As this is your first question ever, just so you know if it works, please accept answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235. Otherwise, please  provide feedback (your Selenium version, browser info, stacktrace, etc.) here to diagnose.

Comment: ActionChains is the construct I was looking for, however, i dont understand the down vote on the question. Discouraging for a beginner and the answer will help others, I am sure.

Comment: Thanks very much - I never would have figured this out without your help. How did you know to try ActionChain instead of just tacking on a click() method? Is it safe/preferred to use ActionChains as default method for clicking elements?

Comment: @user3618690: This is a common practice, one other is to use JavaScript clicking. But nope, it's still recommended to use normal clicks, [native events](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) may have all kinds of browser compatibility issues.